# Как в pandas при чтении read_csv() сохранить тип столбца int если в нем есть пропуски и заменить пропуски нулем?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, int, nan

Известно, что `pandas`  при четнии `csv-file`  `read_csv()` меняет тип столбца на `float`, если в нем есть NaN.  Вот например:

```
like_csv_file = io.StringIO(
"""
text,int1,int2
text1, 1, 1
text2, ,2
text3, 3,
"""
)
x = pd.read_csv(like_csv_file)
print(x)
```

Выдаст такое

```
    text  int1   int2
0  text1     1    1.0
1  text2          2.0
2  text3     3    NaN
```

а

```
x.dtypes
Out[17]: 
text    object
int1    object
int2    float64
dtype: object
```

Относительно недавно появились специальные обозначения для типа `int`, предназначенные, как я понял, для преодоления этой ситуации при явном указании типов столбцов:

```
dtypes = dict(text='string',  int1='Int32',   int2='Int64')
x = pd.read_csv(r"D:\_\SNAP\like_csv.csv", dtype=dtypes, skipinitialspace=True,) 

In [40]: print(x)

    text  int1  int2
0  text1     1     1
1  text2  <NA>     2
2  text3     3  <NA>

In [41]: x.dtypes
Out[41]: 
text    string
int1     Int32
int2     Int64
dtype: object
```

Меня лично устраивает, чтобы во время чтения для "целых" столбцов    были автоматически заменены на ноль, но я не знаю, как это сделать, поэтому приходится делать еще одну команду:

```
x.loc[:,['int1','int2']] = x[['int1','int2']].fillna(0)
print(x)

    text  int1  int2
0  text1     1     1
1  text2     0     2
2  text3     3     0
```

Можно как то это сделать прямо при чтении `read_csv()` и только для целых столбцов, так как добавлять в "строковые" столбцы нули нехорошо.

Файлов читается много и приходится запоминать для каждой таблицы целочисленные столбцы, чтобы делать в них потом  `.fillna(0)`, хотелось бы делать это в момент считывания.  Я это сделал вот так.

```
x = pd.read_csv(r"D:\_\SNAP\like_csv.csv", dtype=dtypes, skipinitialspace=True,).fillna(
         value={key:0 for key, value in dtypes.items() if value in ('Int32', 'Int64')})
```

Но может есть какие-то более изящные и удобочитаемые способы?
Я имею ввиду - нет ли каких параметров или возможностей у самого `read_csv()` ?

Comment: Вы можете вместо текущей конструкции в fillna в параметре value просто указать словарь, а не его генератор. value = {"int1":0," int2":0}.

Comment: потому и генератор,  что чтение файлов массовое, а столбцы разные.
7-12  типов файлов

Comment: Ваш генератор не имеет смысла, потому что вы явно задаете названия колонок. то есть, можно обойтись словарем